# Nginx config with try_files and rewrite: precedence?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to rationalize my Nginx server config, but I have a rather dumb question that I couldn't solve. So, here is the question : is `try_files` parsed before or after `rewrite` ? Asked differently, Do I have to put `try_files` after *all* `rewrite` directives, or is Nginx config parser smart enough to evaluate `try_files` *after* all relevant `rewrite` directives ?

The link with the config rationalization is that the answer to this question will change the organisation of the config, ie if config file order of `try_files` and `rewrite` changes the config behaviour, it will force me to disperse my includes, some of them containing `try_files` and other ones containing `rewrite`, because I also have `rewrite` directly in `nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nginx process request in phases, and `rewrite`'s phase is always **before** `try_files` phase.
Therefore the order of these directives in config doesn't matter.

Comment: Just to be sure : you know that from the documentation and I missed it, or is it your experience ?

Comment: There is page on nginx wiki http://wiki.nginx.org/Phases. Also it's in source code https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http.c#L477

Comment: Dammit ! I was looking in http://nginx.org/en/docs/, not in http://wiki.nginx.org/Main ; I was under the impression that this wiki was to be closed and not maintained. My fault. Thanks a lot for your help, Alexey.